# $mdDialog when invoked send additional request to api

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, mddialog

I use mdDialog for creating new objects in my web application. Whenever I invoke mdDialog, it always invoke all methods which I have in my angular controller. How can i prevent it?

Here is a short example of my angular controller with mdDialog function

```
    //whenever i click on button which invokes showCreateTask function
    //these 3 methods get invoked also and send request to my api
    $scope.timeline = new TimelineService();
    $scope.users = UserService.getChatUsers();
    $scope.projects = ProjectService.query();

    /*********DIALOGS************/
    $scope.hide = function () {
        $mdDialog.hide();
    };

           $scope.cancel = function () {
        $mdDialog.cancel();
    };

    $scope.answer = function (answer) {
        $mdDialog.hide(answer);
    };

    $scope.createTask = function () {
        TaskService.save($scope.task, function () {
        });
    }

    $scope.showCreateTask = function (ev) {
        $mdDialog.show({
            controller: TaskController,
            templateUrl: 'app/components/templates/CreateTaskDialog.html',
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            targetEvent: ev,
            clickOutsideToClose: true,
            fullscreen: false,
            scope: $scope,
            preserveScope: true,
            onComplete: function () {
                //Timepicker
                angular.element(".timepicker").timepicker({
                    showMeridian: false,
                    showInputs: false,
                    minuteStep: 5,
                    defaultTime: '00:00'
                });
            }
        })
        .then(function () {

        }, function () {
            //fail
        });
    };
```

I found out that this `controller: TaskController` cause my problem but I dont know how to solve it. If I remove controller from function, nothing will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this problem with creating nested controller especially for this mdDialog so it cant invoke anything else except what is in my new controller. As reference about nesting controller I used https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller